# Displaying notification in Android application

Tags: android, android-notifications

Actually I have two questions regarding notification implementation I am trying to achieve in my application:

**1. Notification opening automatically** : I am trying to notify on the phone during an event in my application. The notification is functioning correctly in the way that when the event is fired, the intent which I have set in the notification gets called and the screen which I need to display is shown. However the notification comes on status bar for a second and then disappears. My application which was in background automatically comes in foreground because of the notification. I don't want the application to come on foreground automatically. I just need to display the notification.

**2. Displaying notification on locked screen** : With the following code, I am not able to display notification on **locked screen**.

This is the code I have used to display the notification :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Trip Alert");
        mBuilder.setContentText(StringUtils.join("You have reached ",destination.getAddress()));
        mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessages);
        mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent();
        detailIntent.setClass(DestinationListActivity.this,
                DestinationDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra("Destination", destination);
        startActivityForResult(detailIntent, 1);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(DestinationDetailActivity.class);

        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(detailIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
```

The reason notification is getting displayed for a very little time is because I have written following code in the `DestinationDetailsActivity onCreate` :

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.cancel(100);  
..  
}
```

**But if this code won't come here, how shall I dismiss the notification?**

Please do let me know if I need to explain more.

Comment: startActivityForResult(detailIntent, 1); Remove this!!!!

Comment: This is a requirement. I am displaying details screen on tap on notification. Thus destination object has to be shown so as to display the data. Also startActivityForResult is called as I am returning some data from details screen.

Comment: Removing what you asked answers my first question. But then when I am in detail screen from notification, and I tap Back hardware key, application goes in background instead of going to previous activity.

Comment: @SunilMishra : First question solved. I did what you suggested. And in pending intent, set result code as 1 instead of 0. Can you provide solution for second question ?

Comment: stackBuilder.addParentStack(DestinationDetailActivity.class); Add your parent class here!